# Drilltrough to a specific page

Tags: reporting-services

Is it anyway possible to do Drilltrough (Action > Go to report) that points to a specific page number? Say, even if the target report has a @PageNum parameter, what can that report do with that information, in order to show that page?

Comment: I can place a bookmark at the beginning of every page, containing the value of that page. But still we can only do either Drilltrough, or Go to bookmark, not both.

Comment: The restriction: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f7498b63-05b7-42ff-96af-22b45ef6489b/jump-to-report-specific-bookmark?forum=sqlreportingservices.